# How to split a string into a List<string> from a multi-line TextBox that adds '\n\r' as line endings?

Tags: c#, arrays, string

I've got a textbox in my XAML file:

```
<TextBox 
             VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" 
             AcceptsReturn="True" 
             Width="400" 
             Height="100" 
             Margin="0 0 0 10" 
             Text="{Binding ItemTypeDefinitionScript}"
             HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
```

with which I get a string that I send to `CreateTable(string)` which in turn calls `CreateTable(List<string>)`.

```
public override void CreateTable(string itemTypeDefinitionScript)
{
    CreateTable(itemTypeDefinitionScript.Split(Environment.NewLine.ToCharArray()).ToList<string>());
}

public override void CreateTable(List<string> itemTypeDefinitionArray)
{
    Console.WriteLine("test: " + String.Join("|", itemTypeDefinitionArray.ToArray()));
}
```

The problem is that the string obviously has '\n\r' at the end of every line so Split('\n') only gets one of them as does Split('\r'), and using Environment.Newline.ToCharArray() when I type in this:

```
one
two
three
```

produces this:

```
one||two||three
```

but I want it of course to produce this:

```
one|two|three
```

**What is a one-liner to simply parse a string with '`\n\r`' endings into a `List<string>`?**

Comment: Are you sure it's `\n\r` and not the other way around?

Comment: it could be the other way around, but I would think Environment.NewLine would have it in the right order so it could just split the line on those two characters as a unit separator

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Something like this could work:

```
string input = "line 1\r\nline 2\r\n";
List<string> list = new List<string>(
                           input.Split(new string[] { "\r\n" }, 
                           StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries));
```

Replace `"\r\n"` with a separator string suitable to your needs.

Answer (score 19):

try this:

```
List<string> list = new List<string>(Regex.Split(input, Environment.NewLine));
```

Answer (score 8):

Use the overload of [`string.Split`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tabh47cf.aspx) that takes a `string[]` as separators:

```
itemTypeDefinitionScript.Split(new [] { Environment.NewLine }, 
                               StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Answer (score 6):

Minor addition:

```
List<string> list = new List<string>(
                           input.Split(new string[] { "\r\n", "\n" }, 
                           StringSplitOptions.None));
```

will catch the cases without the "\r" (I've many such examples from ancient FORTRAN FIFO codes...) and not throw any lines away.

Comment: Does `\r\n` and `\n` cover all cases? I mean, since now C# is cross-platform, I wonder if there is some other OS that uses a different separator for new line.